# Google two-step verification doesn't want to work. Pops up, I approve and nothing happens

Tags: samsung, google-account, google, samsung-galaxy-note-9

Phone is a Samsung Note 9  SM-960F model. The phone is running Android 10. And I never experienced this problem on any other phone, model or Android version before.

Basically I am logged into my Google account. Every Google service works great. Except two-step verification.

- I get the "notification" in Chrome for example when I sign in on a new PC. All great.
- The phone makes a notification sound, the two step verification pops up.
- I tap "Yes", I get a toast notification "Approved".... and nothing happens.

What could cause this and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this issue before and in the end it turned out to just be a server-side outage / traffic.  Either wait it out after submitting or try again in a bit if it times out, but don't spam requests as it'd likely contribute to the delays.  Feel free to confirm it's not an network/carrier/ISP connectivity issue on your end first (e.g., switch to mobile data or vice versa), but when it last occured I was quite peeved there was no mention anywhere on Google's end in support resources regarding ongoing outages.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the answer. Thought it's something on my end...

Answer (score 0):

I just had it now: Clicking yes has absolutely 0 impact on the button, as if the screen is frozen (no button vfx).

For me, the solution was to either reboot the phone and/or disable VPN: One of these two did the trick **immediately** after the reboot was done!