# Nothing happen when 'Tap yes' in Google 2-step Verification

Tags: security, google-account, google, google-authenticator

Phone is Sugar C13. The phone is running Android 8.1.0.

When I sign in Chrome on PC, I get the "notification" of "Is it you trying to sign in?", and the two step verification pops up.
I tap "Yes", and nothing happens.

What could cause this and how could I fix this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Google two-step verification doesn't want to work. Pops up, I approve and nothing happens](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221621/44325)

Comment: Yes, it's related. But it differs.  When I tap "Yes", I didn't  get a toast notification "Approved".... and nothing happens.

Comment: Strange thing is that other google services work fine.